# Trouble understanding a derivation in Griffith's QM: How to nondimensionalise Schrödinger eq. to $\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\left(\xi^2-K\right)\psi$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, dimensional-analysis

I have trouble understanding a derivation in Griffith's QM: How to nondimensionalise Schrödinger equation to $$\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\left(\xi^2-K\right)\psi \quad .$$

The book explains it like so (at page 51). We start with the Schrödinger equation:

$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}+\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2x^2\psi=E\psi \quad .$$

Then a dimensionless variable $\xi$ gets introduced:

$$\xi=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}x \quad ,$$

which turns Schrödinger equation into:

$$\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\left(\xi^2-K\right)\psi \quad .$$

Where $K$ is defined as:

$$K=\frac{2E}{\hbar\omega} \quad .$$

If I try to solve it first for $\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}$ I get:
$$\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=\left(-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}+\frac{m^2\omega^2x^2}{\hbar^2}\right)\psi \quad .$$

I don't know how to proceed, could somoene help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I need to convert the derivatives:
$$
\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d}{dx}\psi\right)
$$
$$
\frac{d}{dx}=\frac{d\xi}{dx}\frac{d}{d\xi}=\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}\frac{d}{d\xi}
$$
So then we have
$$
\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\left(-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}+\frac{m^2\omega^2x^2}{\hbar^2}\right)\psi
$$
Then I'll substitute $\xi$ for $x$
$$
\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\left(-\frac{2mE}{\hbar^2}+\frac{m\omega\xi^2}{\hbar}\right)\psi
$$
And I just divide both sides
$$
\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}=\left(-\frac{2E}{\hbar\omega}+\xi^2\right)\psi
$$
All good.

Comment: Ah so if I understand correctly, to convert $$\frac{d^2\psi}{dx^2}\rightarrow\frac{d^2\psi}{d\xi^2}$$ you just have to do the following: $$\frac{d^2}{d\xi^2}=\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}\frac{d}{d\xi}\right)\left(\sqrt{\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}}\frac{d}{d\xi}\right)=\frac{m\omega}{\hbar}\frac{d^2}{d\xi^2}\ $$?

Comment: yes that's right. but you made a typo. The left side of the second equation should be $d^/dx^2$

Comment: Ah yeah I see. Thank you very much for the help